# Is there a limit on the length of the needle in the PHP strpos function?

Tags: php, strpos

My questions are simple:

1. Is there a limitation as to what the length of a strpos needle can be?
2. If so, is there a way to get around it?

It seems like my longer needles don't trigger a position whereas my shorter length ones do.

example:

```
if (strpos($data, "You were not able to complete this job. Please try again at a later date. Do not hit your back button.") !== false)
//solves as false

if (strpos($data, "You were not able") !== false)
//returns the position
```

Comment: Please post a use-case that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Define `longer` needles. How long is long? Seems likely that the problem here is case or character set related, `strpos()` performs a binary comparison and will not take these into account. If you pass in a needle that is too long for it to cope with, most likely outcome is an out of memory error or a segfault.

Comment: posted example.  the difference between lengths is not that large.

Comment: I have different scenarios using different lengths of text. I noticed things were not working on the long ones. I shortened them and they work but I cannot determine why this is happening

Comment: @KiloJKilo http://codepad.org/A0X7Gylc - Can you show what is in your `$data` variable as well...?

Comment: my data from a cURL obtained webpage. The text is in a simple <b></b> tag

Comment: due to the nature of the html, I would not be able to post it. I'm sorry

Comment: You sure there aren't any HTML tags, tabs in place of spaces, etc. in the `$data` text? Maybe two spaces after a sentence? Anything different at all from your needle on a byte-by-byte basis? If you don't see a difference, trying looping through each string character by character, comparing each one directly, perhaps also printing their [`ord()`](http://php.net/ord) values.

Comment: the encoding of your php file and the page from which you take the data coincide?

Comment: Are you sure the letter cases match exactly?

Comment: @Wiseguy I copy the text from the source of the page.

Comment: @Laxus I think so. If it matches one length wouldn't that indicate the $data is good?

Comment: @KiloJKilo If the second example matches (with the shorter text), try [this](http://codepad.org/Z7TWS4Lm) to obtain a hex dump from the string and it should help you see why it doesn't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The problem lies elsewhere:* while there is likely *some* implementation limit (e.g. 2GB?), it is not this limit.

Presumably the longer needle just *doesn't match* the input:

- Extra spaces? Remember browsers will "collapse" consecutive HTML whitespace. A "copy'n'paste" from a browser might therefore be *different* than what cURL reads. (This could also extend to other source not rendered-as-text in a browser.)
- Things-that-look-like-spaces-but-aren't? (Tabs or newlines?)
- Or something else that causes the input (and/or needled) to differ from expected ..

Comment: Thank you. I do not set the header or encoding options with my cURL execution. Do you think some issues could be occurring with that? If I set the encoding and say, browser options to something standard, it may return a more normal page?

Comment: @KiloJKilo I would use a tool like fiddler2 to investigate. It can be used to see the actual data in several different forms and will reveal if the client (and/or headers) used alters the servers response ..

Comment: I started using direct html coding rather then what was being displayed and everything has worked out. Thanks